# Display specific word for column after aggregation SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregation

Is there any way in SQL Server i can choose a specific string to display after grouping by?

e.g.

```
SELECT MIN(MovieName) AS [Movie Name], Genre
FROM Movie
GROUP BY Genre
```

which results:

```
Movie Name     Genre
   Anon        Sci-fi
```

Now i know you can use min/max for that column but is there anyway i can display "star trek" for example.

```
 Movie Name    Genre
 Star Trek     Sci-fi
```

sql fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e12fa/6

Comment: what is the rule for this ? Why display 'star trek' instead of 'anon' ?

Comment: Is your requirement that you only want one row to display and it may vary ?

Comment: @Shaneis MAX returns star wars

Comment: @RyanGadsdon Add more details into the question if you need some help.

Comment: @JibinBalachandran theres no more detail to add? Is there anyway i can display "Star Trek" under movie name using aggregation

Comment: But why `Star Trek`? Why not `Anon` or `Star Wars`? Even they come under the same genre.

Comment: @JibinBalachandran theres no particular reason but i want to know if this is possible to display specific values when grouping

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @RyanGadsdon You mean you don't want to display the max or min but you want to use `MIN()` or `MAX()` for displaying some specific value?? Doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I assume there is actually kind of real-life rule for preferring some instead of others like "most popular" or "newest" or "my favorite" per genre. However your solution has nothing to do with that. You should define the task you are trying to accomplish and requirements the appropriate solution must conform to.

Comment: e.g. if i wanted to group by sci-fi i know more people would know of star trek than anon so this result would be more useful to display when it comes to that specific genre

Comment: So you want to display a well known serie toghether with each genre ?

Comment: @RyanGadsdon Then you need add some column like `popularity` and then query it accordingly. Your DBMS won't know that ` star trek` is more popular than `anon` unless it has some data related to that.

Comment: Then you should add a column in the movie table to mark wich serie name you want to display in your query, or add popularity info like suggested in above comments

Comment: you can do SELECT MAX('Star Trek') FROM #Movie

Comment: You might want to add an additional table "GenreRepresentative" or similar, where you add the desired titles per genre. Another approach might be to add a CASE for your genre, such as `CASE WHEN Genre = 'SciFI' THEN 'StarTrek' ELSE 'other SciFi' END AS GenreRepresentatice`and then group by this case.

Comment: I understand i can add other data which would create it based on popularity i just wondered if there was a quick solution to manually choose it

Comment: quick and very very very very dirty solution is to use a case statement as suggested by @Tyron78

Comment: @GuidoG yes, I know - therefore I suggested a mapping table first. ;-) Always depends on how fast the result has to be produced :-D

Comment: @Tyron78 Yes the mapping or basing it on popularity is the way to go. If he does wants to do it the quick and dirty method than I suggest doing it in a view, so when a new genre is added you can update the view and dont have to change the client

Comment: @RyanGadsdon I gave you an answer with 3 solutions, the first solution is the best one. But its up to you how you want to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**solution based on popularity :**

```
declare @Movie TABLE (
    MovieName varchar(25),
    Genre varchar(20),
    popularity int
)

INSERT INTO @Movie (MovieName, Genre, popularity)
VALUES ('Star Wars', 'Sci-fi', 0),
       ('Anon',      'Sci-fi', 0),
       ('Star Trek', 'Sci-fi', 1),
       ('Moon',      'Sci-fi', 0),
       ('Csi',       'Crime',  0)

select m.Genre, 
       (select top 1 m2.MovieName from @Movie m2 where m2.Genre = m.Genre order by m2.popularity desc) as MovieName 
from   @Movie m
group by m.Genre
```

result is

```
Genre   MovieName   
_________________
Crime   Csi 
Sci-fi  Star Trek
```

There is no maintenance needed for this solution, it will keep working correct.

**Quick and dirty solution :**

first create a view

```
create view vwMovie as       
  select Genre,
         case when Genre = 'Sci-fi' then 'Star Trek'
              when Genre = 'Crime' then 'Csi'
              else 'unknown'
         end as MovieName
  from   Movie
  group by Genre
```

now use this query in your client

```
select * from vwMovie
```

The result is exact the same as above.
But if anything changes (new genre or you want to show `firefly` in stead of `star trek`) then you don't have to alter your client, but just alter the view in the database.
So the maintenance is still somewhat possible.

**Quick and VERY dirty solution :**

```
select Genre,
       case when Genre = 'Sci-fi' then 'Star Trek'
            when Genre = 'Crime' then 'Csi'
            else 'unknown'
       end as MovieName
from   @Movie
group by Genre
```

The result is exact the same as above.
But if anything changes (new genre or you want to show `firefly` in stead of `star trek`) then you have to alter your client.
So maintenance is very hard because you have to update your client everywhere.